# how can i get the message object after to replying to a message in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to retrive the ID of a message that i just sent in discord.js
With the normal channel.send i have already figured out how to do it.

```
channel.send("message").then(msgFromBot => {
var id = msgFromBot.id //outputs whatever the id of the message my bot just sent
})
```

But when using msg.reply instead of it returning the message object it returns void instead:

```
msg.reply("message").then(msgFromBot => {
    var id = msgFromBot.id //outputs undefined if everything is normal
})
```

Is there any good way of finding out the id of the reply my bot just sent? So not the message that the bot replied to, but the actual message the bot sent?

Comment: Does `msgFromBot` return anything

Comment: is that your whole code? Does it have a `.catch`?

Comment: Did you try logging the `msgFromBot` variable in the reply to the console? According to documentation (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) it should be returning a Promise with the Message object